# Recovery from system crash during update

Tags: system-installation, data-recovery

I was recently updating packages on my Ubuntu 18 installation (graphically) when my laptop overheated and stopped. I am now unable to boot properly into the currently installed kernel or any of the old ones. It appears to have stalled after building the nvidia modules.

I have the following kernels available in the boot menu:

4.18.0-14-generic
4.18.0-14-generic (recovery mode)
4.15.0-45-generic
4.15.0-45-generic (recovery mode)
4.15.0-39-generic
4.15.0-39-generic (recovery mode)
4.15.0-32-generic
4.15.0-32-generic (recovery mode)

If I try to boot into 4.18.0-14 or 4.15.0-45 (either normal or recovery mode) I get the following error:

---[ end Kernel panic – not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---

I am able to boot into 4.15.0-39-generic (recovery mode) and get into emergency mode with the following errors

[Boot errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc3F3.png)

Below is the end of the term.log file from /var/log/apt/term.log which I believe shows the NVidia modules being built and the installing failing trying to build the kernel module.

[Apt Installation log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6iTQ.jpg)

So now I am wondering about my options. Is there a way to recover the update and install from the command line or should I be looking at reinstall options? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you have access to USB devices, I would suggest making a live USB (the install USB) and using this to copy your data to a USB HDD or other USB devices.

Comment: Thanks. I do have a live USB that I can use and I will look at backing things up. Any suggestions for how to proceed after that?

Comment: I've seen question before about failed upgrades - my own opinion is that they are a disaster, and a reinstall is needed.  It *may* be possible to fix the broken upgrade, but it may be a lot of work as well.

Comment: After some digging I removed the newest kernel version using `sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-image-4.18.0-14-generic' rebooted and was able to boot into my old kernel with no issues. From what I understand I have to wait until 2 days from now to post this as an answer.

Comment: Please write the "solution" as an answer.

Comment: @durn2000  It's two or three days to accept your own answer - Please see [https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)  There is a 15 point requirement, but you should have 10 pts now  :)

Comment: Thanks, yes I thought it made sense to post it right away and then come back and put it as an answer when I was able. Sorry new to this and don't know the rules.